# A special Segmentation fault,I don't know why

Tags: c, printf, fault, getc

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int count[26];
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        count[i]=0;
    }
    printf("xx1");
    FILE *p;
    printf("xx");
    p=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(p==NULL)
        printf("error");
    int x=fgetc(p);
    while(x!='\0'){
        count[x-97]++;
        x=getc(p);
        }
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        printf("%c:%d\t",i+97,count[i]);
    }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

here are my codes,when I run to getc().Mistake happend...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:37
37  getc.c: 没有那个文件或目录.

Comment: This is a simple program to count alphabet in a test file.

Comment: `count[x-97]` doesn't make any sense and is probably the reason for the bug.

Comment: What input do you provide? What do you expect to happen when you enter `\n` or any non-alphabet character?

Comment: Try changing `count[x-97]++;` to `if (x>='a' && x<='z') count[x-'a']++;', and perhaps change `while(x!='\0')` to `while(x!=EOF)`. You're unlikely to find any zero bytes inside a text file.

Comment: `if(islower(x)) { count[x - 'a']++; }`

Comment: @r3mainer Use `islower()` rather than testing character ranges yourself.

Comment: Or, `if(isalpha(x)) { count[tolower(x) - 'a']++ }`

Comment: OT: your test `if(p==NULL) printf("error");` is bogous. You do not only need to print the error message but you need to prevent any access to the invalid FILE pointer..

Comment: Thanks all your guys.Many mistakes exit in my codes.I will correct them you mentioned and be careful later.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize the comments:

First of all, `'\0'` is end of string, **not** end-of-file. So instead of:

```
while(x!='\0'){
```

you should do this:

```
while (x != EOF) {
```

Secondly, you should verify that `x-97` is in the index range of `count` before doing:

```
count[x-97]++;
```

Third, your function should not continue if `p == NULL`.